# ¿Funciona realmente especificar un margin y un padding a 0 inicialmente?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

He visto que es muy común que nada más empezar el css, muchos ficheros empiezan con:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Utilizado en teoría para que todos los elementos no tengan padding ni margin.
¿Realmente esto funciona? Porque he tenido muchas veces que modificar algún elemento. No se si es porque utilizo librerías como Bootstrap, que hace que los elementos tengan una serie de propiedades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funcionar funciona, ha sido una forma de resetear el padding y margen desde hace [bastante tiempo](https://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/). (Aunque he encontrado fuentes más antiguas)

Sin embargo, hay motivos para no usarlo, el autor del mismo blog se [arrepintió](https://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/) meros meses después de su decisión.

¿El problema? El rendimiento de la página disminuye, esta respuesta de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful-and-why) da más información sobre el por qué, pero el motivo es simple: El elemento estrella aplica a todos los elementos del DOM, y ciertas páginas web pueden tener cientos de ellos.

También recuerda que la clase/propiedad aplicada al elemento es la [última especificada](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) en el css, por lo que no funcionará si se declara otro margen o espaciado tras la declaración inicial.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que funciona, pero si añades bootstrap o cualquier otro css a buen seguro añadira margenes a los elementos que se considere.

Sobre el rendimiento, se han hecho pruebas con cantidades "extremas" de codigo y selectores como *{...}  y la diferencia [era del orden de milisegundos](https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/), los motores están ya muy optimizados y la carga de resetear con * es despreciable en css.
Otra cosa seria utilizar en JS/Jquery, ahi si que lastraria el rendimiento de forma considerable.